# Google Cloud Functions - Custom library used in many function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 functions on Google Cloud Functions, using python, that use the same library.

The file organization I have is:

```
/libs/libCommon.py
/funcA/main.py
/funcB/main.py
```

Both function A and function B use libCommon.

Through the docs I only see ways for including subdirectories.
There is no clear way to include a parent directory.

What's the best way to organize the code?

Thanks

Comment: If you are in Cloud Functions and not in Cloud Functions for Firebase. You just need to deploy each function in a folder like the following. `/funcA/main.py` `/funcA/libCommon.py` & `/funcB/main.py` `/funcB/libCommon.py`. Otherwise if you are in Cloud Functions for Firebase i'm not sure if this is the recommended way. Note that you have to perform 2 deployments, one per function.

Comment: What's the trigger of the functions?

Comment: I know this is tagged as firebase, but since you used the term Google Cloud Functions in your title, could you please confirm if you are deploying [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) or [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)?

Comment: @pessolato I am deploying functions with no Firebase. Thanks

Comment: @guillaume blaquiere, sometimes http calls. Sometimes storage events. Thanks

Comment: @Christian Ginzalez: The problem there is I have 2 copies of the library to mantain. That's why I wanted to put it on a folder shared by both functions

Comment: In that case you can just upload the library to a repository such git, cloud repository... and reference to the external library in your requirements.txt

Answer (score 2):

You can't share code between functions. However you have several solution to achieve this:

- Create a package, deploy on PiPy and add this as dependency in your `requirements.txt` file. Issue -> PiPy is public without souscription
- Create a deployment script which copy the source where they should be, and then run the `gcloud` command -> I'm not fan of scripting, especially if your project becomes complex
- Use Cloud Run instead of Function. You can create 2 different containers or only one with 2 entry points. Cloud Run has many advantages.

  - If your request can be processed in parallel on the same instance, you can save money.
  - If not, set the concurrency param to 1 (same behavior as function).
  - Your code can be shared between several endpoints.
  - Your code is portable
  - Your service has always 1vCPU for processing, memory is customizable. [You can also save money compare to function](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e)

Of course, I'm Cloud Run fan, but I think it's the best solution. About Storage event, it's not an issue. [Set up a notification to publish storage event to PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes) and then set up a Push Subscription to your service

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still not ready resign doing it in cloud functions. I am not a fan of the build script suggestion, but also not too much in love with the Cloud Run PubSub solution for Cloud Storage.

The downside of cloud run is that you can't really think the solutionas a composition of independent microservices.

So far, I will a bit and if not go for the scripting solution.